# Installing Rails ERROR: could not find rails locally or in a repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been poking around the internet looking for a solution on this one... with no luck..
I'm new to rails... If anyone has an idea, I'd love to hear it. Much appreciated!

I enter:

```
LW:src liamwright$ sudo gem install rails --include-dependencies
```

And Get:

```
INFO:  `gem install -y` is now default and will be removed
INFO:  use --ignore-dependencies to install only the gems you list
Bulk updating Gem source index for: http://gems.rubyforge.org
ERROR:  could not find rails locally or in a repository
```

I am running:

```
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [universal-darwin9.0]
Mac OS X 10.5.8
```

I also tried:

```
gem sources -r gems.rubyonrails.org
```

And Get:

```
source gems.rubyonrails.org not present in cache
```

Answer (score 2):

Might want to make sure you have the newest rubygems:

```
sudo gem install rubygems-update
sudo gem update --system
```

Then:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: Installing gemcutter shouldn't be necessary - it just includes the tools to push gems since gems.rubyforge.org points to gemcutter.

Comment: Oh that's right, I forgot that gemcutter got promoted to the actual official gem server.

Answer (score 2):

Just to check...

...try doing a `sudo gem update --system` before installing Rails to make sure you have the latest RubyGems installed?

EDIT: Actually, if your RubyGems install is really old, you might need to follow the [alternate directions on Gemcutter](http://gemcutter.org/pages/download).

Answer (score 1):

I came across this solution on [Albertux' blox](http://albertux.ayalasoft.com/2008/09/30/rubygems-update-issue-on-ubuntu/). Running this script will fix it (It worked perfectly for me on an Ubuntu 9.10 machine):

```
#!/bin/bash
#(download the latest on http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126)
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/43984/rubygems-update-1.3.0.gem
sudo gem install rubygems-update-1.3.0.gem
sudo update_rubygems
# now this work:
sudo gem update --system
echo "done."
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem trying to upgrade rubygems from 1.2.0 to 1.3.7.

Setp-1)
So I just downloaded rubygems-update-1.3.7.gem from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126

Setp-2)
gem install rubygems-update-1.3.7.gem

Setp-3)
update_rubygems

and it work for me.