# Installing Rails ERROR on Windows XP: could not find rails locally or in a repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978167/installing-rails-error-could-not-find-rails-locally-or-in-a-repository). However, that is related to installing on non-windows platform. I followed the instructions [here](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/getting-started/installation/windows) and get error when I execute the following:-

```
gem install rails
```

The error is following:-

ERROR:  http://gems.rubyforge.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  could not find gem rails locally or in a repository

I am trying to use v1.8.6-26. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An excellent installer for a developer;

> BitNami RubyStack greatly simplifies
>   the development and deployment of Ruby
>   on Rails applications. It includes
>   ready-to-run versions of Apache,
>   MySQL, Ruby and Rails and required
>   dependencies. It can be deployed using
>   a native installer, as a virtual
>   machine or in the cloud.

========================================

More at:
http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack